# Select Query in C# using AND, OR

Tags: c#, sql

I have a winform C# SQL app in  that i'm trying to fetch data from a table using following query

```
fth.CommandText = "
Select Enrollment_No, Student_Name 
from Final_Result_Master 
where Sub_1=@Sub 
    and Sub_1_stat=@sta Or Sub_2=@Sub 
    and Sub_2_stat=@sta Or Sub_3=@Sub 
    and Sub_3_stat=@sta Or Sub_4=@Sub 
    and Sub_4_stat=@sta Or Sub_5=@Sub 
    and Sub_5_stat=@sta Or Sub_6=@Sub 
    and Sub_6_stat=@sta Or Sub_7=@Sub 
    and Sub_7_stat=@sta Or Sub_8=@Sub 
    and Sub_8_stat=@sta Or Sub_9=@Sub 
    and Sub_9_stat=@sta Or Sub_10=@Sub 
    and Sub_10_stat=@sta Or Sub_11=@Sub 
    and Sub_11_stat=@sta Or Sub_12=@Sub 
    and Sub_12_stat=@sta";
```

after wards i'm displaying it in a data gridview.

But the problem is that the data grid view only has column names i.e Enrollment_No and Student_Name and there is no other data withing the grid
refer image
[image: no rows]

I tried to execute the same query in SSMS and it gave me output e.g 4 enrollment No's and 4 Names.

But c# commandtext does not return any rows... 
What could be the problem???

Comment: don't your request lack of `(` & `)` to surround your AND OR

Comment: `Sub_12`? o_O .......

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond like this? (Sub_1_stat=@sta)

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to do and how you want to filter your result.
But you have several AND & OR whitout any (). this sounds weird

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond What i'm trying to do is like this my table consists for 12 subject names from sub_1 to Sub_12 with thier status Sub_1_stat to Sub_12_stat. Status is generally pass or fail. the thing is that at a not all 12 subs have values some have "N/A". now i'm trying to find out in which subject how many student have passed.

Comment: @RagingBull's answer is imo what you want

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond There are no rows in the grid....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use brackets properly when combining `AND` and `OR` in `WHERE` clause:

Try this:

```
fth.CommandText = "Select Enrollment_No, Student_Name 
       from Final_Result_Master 
       where (Sub_1=@Sub and Sub_1_stat=@sta) 
       or (Sub_2=@Sub and Sub_2_stat=@sta)   
       Or (Sub_3=@Sub and Sub_3_stat=@sta) 
       Or (Sub_4=@Sub and Sub_4_stat=@sta) 
       Or (Sub_5=@Sub and Sub_5_stat=@sta) 
       Or (Sub_6=@Sub and Sub_6_stat=@sta) 
       Or (Sub_7=@Sub and Sub_7_stat=@sta) 
       Or (Sub_8=@Sub and Sub_8_stat=@sta) 
       Or (Sub_9=@Sub and Sub_9_stat=@sta) 
       Or (Sub_10=@Sub and Sub_10_stat=@sta)
       Or (Sub_11=@Sub and Sub_11_stat=@sta) 
       Or (Sub_12=@Sub and Sub_12_stat=@sta)";
```

When combining `AND` and `OR` conditions, it is important to use brackets so that the database knows what order to evaluate each condition. (Just like when you were learning the order of operations in Math class!).

Some examples [**here**](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php).

Comment: @REZR.AMX: What values did you try?

Comment: @REZR.AMX: No, values of `@Sub` and `@sta`??

Comment: "Sub is Applied_Physics_1(databound to combobox) and sta is "Pass";

Comment: @REZR.AMX: Are you sure you have a record with `Sub_1=Applied_Physics_1` and `Sub_1_stat=Pass` in table `Final_Result_Master`?